# Do URL rewrites lead to performance problems?

Tags: php, performance, url

This might be a silly question, but since most (PHP) frameworks and CMS's use URL rewrites to redirect all requests to /index.php, doesn't this mean that index.php might have trouble handling all those requests in a high traffic website?

Logically speaking, wouldn't it be more efficient performance-wise to spread the balance by having more than 1 actual PHP-file (index1.php, index2.php and so on)?

Comment: Usually it's the CPU that handle requests, not the files.

Comment: Short answer: yes, it will slow down your server if you use htaccess to rewrite urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to balance the load and want to make your website efficient then you should to load balancing of the server, use a CDN. But, these are generally a lot more expensive and implemented by big firms.

In general you can the httpd.config file of your server to set MAX clients and other properties.. please refer:

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-apache-config.html

And its the operating system which takes care of number of reference made to a particular file. So, Even if a file is referred hundreds of time it won't make any difference in efficiency, as it will only increase the ref count of the file.

Hope this helps!! :)